# How do I build RPMS?

Tags: build, repository, packaging, redhat, rpm

How do I build RPMS under Red Hat?

I need to package a newer version of some software than is available from the repositories.

(I can build it locally already, its just the packaging that I need to do, so that I can use it on other machines)

I could  just take the .spec file from the older version's SRPM and start from there, right? - But i'm brand new to packaging, any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the existing SRPM is a fantastic first step -- trying to build one from scratch is an exercise in frustration, especially if your users expect it to work with previously packaged versions of the same tool.

You'll need to keep the documentation at [rpm.org](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Docs#PackagerDocumentation) handy at all times. The Maximum RPM book is probably a little too dated now, but at one time it was always loaded in one of my browser tabs.

One thing to be very careful of is builds that work on *your* machine but aren't repeatable anywhere else. You really should get a dedicated building environment of some sort set up so you can have repeatable builds.

Comment: Thanks for the info, a link on rpm.org (http://www.gurulabs.com/downloads/GURULABS-RPM-LAB/GURULABS-RPM-GUIDE-v1.0.PDF) seems like it might help me.

Comment: Managed it in the end :) - Built some RPMs for a newer version of JPilot. Built on RHEL6 but run on FC15. Success!